# Copy and Save As several sheets keeping fixed Sheet VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, dynamic, copy

I have a workbook with 15 sheets and I'd like to Save As new Workbooks keeping "Sheet1" fixed.

Like this, after save I'd have files wwith the following sheets:

```
File 1: "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
File 2: "Sheet1", "Sheet3"
File 3: "Sheet1", "Sheet4"
File 4: "Sheet1", "Sheet5"
```

This is what I got so far

```
Sub Splitbook()
Dim xPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet 
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", xWs)).Copy
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As what Tim said, please add context to your question (e.g. things you've tried, specific part of code the doesn't work etc.). If can find time reading this [StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) and then edit your question accordingly, that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I've just editted the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following. Inside a loop over all worksheets you exclude the first one. Then you create a new workbook and copy the two required sheets there. The blank sheets of the new workbook are deleted in a loop - there is probably some more elegant solution to this part, but it works.

```
Sub Splitbook()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Add
            xWs.Copy before:=wb.Worksheets(1)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy before:=wb.Worksheets(1)
            Do While wb.Worksheets.Count > 2
                wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count).Delete
            Loop
            wb.SaveAs xWs.Name
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```